# bs4 beautiful soup does not find div's with div's for some reason

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

the `HTML`:

```html
<div id="divTradeHaltResults"> 
<div class="genTable"
   <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr> 
  <td> 03/10/2020  </td> 
  <td> 15:11:45     </td>
```

the Code:

```py
url = r'https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=TradeHalts'
r=requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('div',{'id':'divTradeHaltResults'})
divclass=table.find('div',{'class':"genTable"})

divt=divclass.find('table')
```

result:

```
divclass={None Type}None
```

I have tried the 'lxml' parser to no avail.
I can get it using Selenium but it uses too many resources.
From checking all other problems around multiple div's
there seems to be and inherent problem with bs4.
Has anyone solved it ? I have tried multiple ideas from other
people.

Comment: Close the tag... `<div class="genTable"` like this: `<div class="genTable">`

Comment: What is the value of `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `None`, that's due the page is loaded dynamically via `JavaScript` which is rendered once the page itself loads.

Therefor I've been able to track the origin of the `table` which from where the `JS` sending an `XHR` request to obtain it. that's can be tracked via your Browser `Developer-Tools` under `Network-Tab`.

Otherwise you can use `selenium` for that. I've included both solution for you.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


json = {
    "id": 2,
    "method": "BL_TradeHalt.GetTradeHalts",
    "params": "[]",
    "version": "1.1"
}

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=TradeHalts'
}

r = requests.post(
    "https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/RPCHandler.axd", json=json, headers=headers).json()

df = pd.read_html(r["result"])[0]

df.to_csv("table1.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/c96b7f280542911d185ba826a1064f24/table1.csv)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get(
    "https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=TradeHalts")

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[2]

# print(df)
df.to_csv("table.csv", index=False)
driver.quit()
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/36d1bc7aafdd2f5492f66c223bc7afa0/table.csv)

Comment: αԋɱҽԃ  
 Thanks
works fine is see the network tab and the RPCHandler.axd call
how do you determine the json content for the requests.post call?

Comment: @MNewton check the params used for the request itself.